# Convert date string in “MM/DD/YY” format

Tags: hadoop, hive

I just saw this example.How can I get this solved.

The Hive metastore contains a database named problem1 that contains a table named customer. The customertable contains 90 million customer records (90,000,000), each with a birthday field.

Sample Data (birthday is in bold)

```
1904287 Christopher Rodriguez   Jan 11, 2003
96391595    Thomas Stewart      6/17/1969
2236067 John Nelson             08/22/54
```

For every row in the solution table, replace the contents of the birthday field with a date string in “MM/DD/YY” format.

MM is the zero-padded month (01-12),
DD is the zero-padded day (01-31),
YY is the zero-padded 2-digit year (00-99)

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(doj,'MM/dd/yyyy')) from temp1;
```

Comment: 2-digit year is not enough for storing 19xx and 20xx years. In your example you have both 2003 and 1969

Comment: I can see many combinations for date field in source table. Can you provide possible list?

Comment: @Ambrish..There us alist of 10000 records..Not sure about how many formats will be there..is ther any generic way

Comment: No there is no generic way

Comment: Check this link to get the format: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Write your own udf that will try to recognize format.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in a generic way, you'll have to test each possible case.
You can do it like this

```
select coalesce(
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(doj ,"MMM dd, yyyy"), "MM/dd/yy"),
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(doj ,"MM/dd/yyyy"), "MM/dd/yy"),
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(doj ,"MM/dd/yy"), "MM/dd/yy")
)
```