# how to verify and match different date formats in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, unix-timestamp

I have below dates in my hive table :

```
Jan 2014
Oct-13
8-Nov
8-Oct
30-Nov-11
```

I need to convert them in the 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.
I have used `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(change_log_date ,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')` to covert date format which is working fine for 30-Nov-11 however since I have different date formats in the data so how to write generic code which will check date format and convert it into 'yyyy-MM-dd'.
I need to put 0 for day/month/year if its not present.

```
for eg. I need to convert 8-Oct into '0000-10-08'
```

need help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date string in “MM/DD/YY” format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634829/convert-date-string-in-mm-dd-yy-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know all possible date format, you can use case statement to apply the correct format for each line:

```
CASE WHEN change_log_date rlike '[0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{2}' 
     THEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(change_log_date ,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
     WHEN change_log_date rlike --other regex 
     THEN -- and so on
```

If you are more familiar with java or python, you can easily write your piece of code and use it as [Hive function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateFunction).