# Hive function to SQL Workbench conversion

Tags: sql, hiveql, psql, postgresql-9.4

I need help in converting below hive function to SQL Workbench (PSQL)

```
to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column,'dd-MMM-yy'))) > cast('2019-08-05' as date)
```

I tried this function in PSQL, but its not working:

```
to_char(to_date(date_column,'MM/dd/yyyy'),'dd-MMM-yy') > cast('2019-08-05' as date)
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks
A

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have it more complicated than it needs to be.

This should be enough for you:

```
to_date(date_column,'MM/dd/yyyy') > cast('2019-08-05' as date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But however there are so many date formats and even null in date column and in turn it is throwing error.

Comment: You can check this question to deal with multiple date formats https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501210/how-to-verify-and-match-different-date-formats-in-hive. And use ```nvl``` or ```coalesce``` functions for dealing with nulls.

Comment: Thanks much! will check it.